# Conditional operations in dataframe (if else)

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, conditional-statements

I have a data frame called Install_Date. I want to assign values to another data frame called age under two conditions- if value in Install_Date is null then `age = current year -  plant construct date`, if value is not null then `age = current year - INPUT_Asset["Install_Date"]`,

This is the code I have. First condition works fine but the second condition still gives 0 as values. :

```
Plant_Construct_Year = 1975

this_year= 2020

for i in INPUT_Asset["Install_Date"]:

    if i != 0.0:
        INPUT_Asset["Asset_Age"] = this_year- INPUT_Asset["Install_Date"]
    else
        INPUT_Asset["Asset_Age"] = this_year- Plant_Construct_Year
```

Comment: Hi and Welcome to So ..!! Please don't use `Urgent` in question title, SO is not a free code writing community , also Please take the time to read this post on [how to provide a great pandas example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20109391/how-to-make-good-reproducible-pandas-examples)

Comment: Have you looked at `df.apply(function)`?

Comment: new to python, don't have much idea. Checking it out.

Comment: Could you add some sample data so we can see the input? You can see my previous questions for easy ways of creating sample data.

Answer (score 0):

```
INPUT_Asset["Install_Date"] = pd.to_numeric(INPUT_Asset["Install_Date"], errors='coerce').fillna(0)

INPUT_Asset["Asset_Age"] = np.where(INPUT_Asset["Install_Date"] ==0.0, this_year- Plant_Construct_Year,INPUT_Asset["Asset_Age"])

INPUT_Asset["Asset_Age"] = np.where(INPUT_Asset["Install_Date"] !=0.0, this_year- INPUT_Asset["Install_Date"],INPUT_Asset["Asset_Age"])

print(INPUT_Asset["Asset_Age"])
```

Comment: This code does the job. But is there a better approach to it?